# Proximity searches in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, geocoding, proximity

What proximity search options are there for Rails? (Perhaps with pros and cons of each?)

- Is a postcode database the way to go?
- or using Geocoding with a gem such as Geocoder?
- Are there any best practises or gotchas to be aware of?

(Example usage, A Yellow Pages type app where businesses can list, and users can enter their postcode and find businesses that are close to them, or within a radius of specified miles.)

**Update:** The app is pretty much exactly like the example app above - Businesses can list in the app which is essential a directory (which will have categories for each type of business) and users can go to a category and sort the results by distance (after entering their postcode - so the businesses closest to them, gets shown first). There will be no searching by name or other criteria - it is a simple go to the 'Boxer Dog Breeders' page and sort by distance.

Answer (score 8):

Well the answer depends on what you want to do. If you want simple proximity searches (within a radius and stuff) then the [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem is more than fine! Now, if you want more advanced search capabilities (polygon, multi-polygon searches etc) I would suggest to go with the [PostrgeSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) database and the wonderful [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) extension. For use with Rails you should definitely check out the [PostGIS adapter for ActiveRecord](https://github.com/dazuma/activerecord-postgis-adapter) which comes from the author of a really nice gem called [RGeo](https://github.com/dazuma/rgeo) which uses the superfast libraries [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos) and [Proj](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj) for the Geospatial calculations.

Otherwise if you find that you need a dedicated search server that has GIS capabilities then you should definitely use [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) and Ruby has a great gem to aid you with ES called [Tire](https://github.com/karmi/tire/).

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gerry - I updated my questions with info about the app, looks like Geocoder will be fine (would you agree?) although, I am worried about the limit to Google's API, which is just 2,500 requests a day - is that an issue for concern? Or will the caching option negate that?

Comment: Well, there are many ways of dealing with caching the geocoding requests. I would suggest using Redis for that, but bear in mind that while your app gets bigger there is a high probability that you will reach the Google API limit sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to add addational search criteria (eg. name of firm, category) or complex sorting and your DB will grow over 10000 I'm recommend using external search server. For example [sphinx search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) + [thinking sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/).

Here is example of geosearching: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/geosearching.html

RoR model solutions (like [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)) are not very efficient with [full text searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - I have updated the question with more info about the app (it will not have other sorting options or searches)

Comment: I wrote some time ago a similar application. I used thinkig_sphinx with [`reverse_geocoded_by`](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) to reverse geocoding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Geocoding myself, but Alex Reisner's [Geocoder](http://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem looks like the best option, by a mile.

> Geocoder is a complete geocoding solution for Ruby. With Rails it adds geocoding (by street or IP address), reverse geocoding (find street address based on given coordinates), and distance queries. It’s as simple as calling geocode on your objects, and then using a scope like Venue.near("Billings, MT").

Checkout the [README](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/README.rdoc) for a full example on how to use it.